# Setting the backButton frame in a subclass of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationbar

For iPad in iOS 5.0 using ARC, I'm using a subclass of `UINavigationBar` to make a custom navigation bar with a broader bar.. the back button on this navigation bar needs to be vertically centred as I'm using a broader back button. Right now, it's hugging the bottom in its natural place.. I know I can recenter it using the `UINavigationItem` on each view controller's viewDidLoad method.

However is it possible to grab back button in the custom subclass of the UINavigationBar that I created so I can use the layoutSubviews to lay it out in vertically centred?

Thanks in advance for your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

please try this,  I think this may help you

```
// image for my back button
UIImage *backButtonImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"];
UIButton *leftBarButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];

// Setting the image for the back button
[leftBarButton setBackgroundImage: backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[leftBarButton addTarget: self action:@selector(backToMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 // setting the frame for the back button
leftBarButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 32);  

// setting the custom button to navigationbars back button
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: leftBarButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
 navigationBar.backItem.leftBarButtonItem
```

Comment: Thank you, may need to use backitem or topitem . however, still can't get to the frame to modify it.. or recenter it